# Discord.py - Why can't I edit someone else's message?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm working on a channel encrypt command and when I go to execute it I get an error saying forbidden 403: cannot edit a message authored by another user how do I fix this or is it even possible

```
async def encrypt_channel(ctx):
    channel = ctx.channel
    messages = await channel.history(limit=None).flatten()

    for message in messages:
        encrypted_message = ''.join([chr(ord(c) + random.randint(1, 10)) for c in message.content])
        await message.edit(content=encrypted_message)
    
    await ctx.send("Channel encrypted! ")
```

Answer (score 2):

No user on Discord can edit messages, that are **not created by himself** - that also counts for **bots**.

In your current code, you get the **message list** from your `channel` object and try to edit these messages. But you get the `discord.Forbidden` error, because **some messages** in this list are **not sent by your bot**, so you **can't** edit them.

Comment: Ahh ok thank you